# How to find payload in hapi

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have the following route in hapijs server. And i am trying to create a new file using ajax.

```
{
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/create',
        config : {
            payload:{
                maxBytes: 10*1024*1024,
                output:'stream',
                parse: true,
                allow: 'multipart/form-data'
            },
            handler: function (request, reply) {
                var data = request.payload;
                if (data.file) { // undefined always
                    var name = data.file.hapi.filename;
                    var path = writePath + '/' + name;
                    var file = fs.createWriteStream(path);

                    file.on('error', reply);

                    data.file.pipe(file);

                    data.file.on('end', function (err) {
                        reply({
                            filename: data.file.hapi.filename,
                            headers: data.file.hapi.headers
                        });
                    });
                } else reply(boom.badRequest('No file found. Please try again.'));
            }
}
```

The above code always give data.file as undefined. Anything am i missing?

In hapi documentation http://hapijs.com/api#requests, when output is `stream`

> 'stream' - the incoming payload is made available via a
>   Stream.Readable interface. If the payload is 'multipart/form-data' and
>   parse is true, fields values are presented as text while files are
>   provided as streams. File streams from a 'multipart/form-data' upload
>   will also have a property hapi containing filename and headers
>   properties.

html code :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/create" method="post">
  <input type="file" id="UniqueFileImporter"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

of course there is no js code, as i simply need to submit the form after selecting a file from system

Comment: Sure you are posting a form with a file input field named `file`? Code above looks correct so we'll need to see code for HTML form and/or AJAX code

Comment: @MattHarrison hey i have added the html, please look if it helps

Answer (score 0):

thanks to Matt Harrison for pointing out mistake, i was missing attribute name in file inputer.

html should be

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/create" method="post">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="UniqueFileImporter"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```